# Postman Script if else condition for null values

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, postman, assertion

I was trying to use if else to access [ ] condition

```
pm.test("Cases here", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    if (jsonData === null) {
        console.log('1');
        postman.setNextRequest("Get Count");
    }
    else {
        console.log('2');
        postman.setNextRequest("Create");
}
})
```

[image]

"I want Condition when empty should print 1"

but my response is getting

[image]

Comment: jsonData is an array?

Comment: @waiaan yes it is an array.

Comment: then you should not use ==null,use jsonData.length===0

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that `jsonData` is an array, you can check its [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length):

```
if (jsonData.length === 0) {
    // ...
}
```

If you're not sure it's an array, you can [make sure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) then check its length:

```
if (Array.isArray(jsonData) && jsonData.length === 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Comparing it with `null` will always result in `false`, because the variable `jsonData` does not hold the value `null`, it holds an array, which is an object, and thus different from `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make **if** a condition like below because it's not `null` it's an `empty array`

```
pm.test("Cases here", function () {
  var jsonData = pm.response.json();
  if (!jsonData || !jsonData.length) { # see condition here
      console.log('1');
      postman.setNextRequest("Get Count");
  }
  else {
     console.log('2');
     postman.setNextRequest("Create");
  }
})
```